# PyTorch runtime error: expected argument to have type long, but got CPUType instead

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model

I'm new to PyTorch and going through [this tutorial](http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html) on the transformer model. I'm using PyCharm on Win10.
For now, I've basically just copy-pasted the example code, but I'm getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have scalar type Long; but got CPUType instead (while checking arguments for embedding)

It seems to be coming from this line

> def encode(self, src, src_mask):
>          return self.encodder(self.src_embed(src), src_mask)

Tbh, I'm not even sure what this means, let alone how I should go about fixing it.
What's a CPUType? When did I create a variable of such type? From looking at the code I'm only using tensors (or numpy arrays)

here's the full error message:

> C:...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn_reduction.py:46: UserWarning: size_average and reduce args will be deprecated, please use reduction='sum' instead.
>     warnings.warn(warning.format(ret))
>   C:/.../PycharmProjects/Transformer/all_the_code.py:263: UserWarning: nn.init.xavier_uniform is now deprecated in favor of nn.init.xavier_uniform_.
>     nn.init.xavier_uniform(p)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/Transformer/all_the_code.py", line 421, in 
>      SimpleLossCompute(model.generator, criterion, model_opt))
>    File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/Transformer/all_the_code.py", line 297, in run_epoch
>     batch.src_mask, batch.trg_mask)
>    File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/Transformer/all_the_code.py", line 30,  in forward
>     return self.decode(self.encode(src, src_mask), src_mask,
>   File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/Transformer/all_the_code.py", line 34, in encode
>      return self.encoder(self.src_embed(src), src_mask)
>   File "C:...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
>     result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>   File "C:...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 92, in forward
>     input = module(input)
>   File "C:...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
>     result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>   File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/Transformer/all_the_code.py", line 218, in forward
>     return self.lut(x) * math.sqrt(self.d_model)
>   File "C:...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
>     result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>   File "C:...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\sparse.py", line 117, in forward
>     self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
>   File "C:...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1506, in embedding
>     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)

Comment: actually, I'm also getting warning messages from the IDE which I have trouble understanding, but I'm not sure if I should ask them in this question, or make a separate question for that.